# Word length frequency count with Linux commannds

Tags: bash, pipe, cygwin

I want to get the frequency count for word lengths (test.txt is a list of words). The code below should calculate the number of words of different lengths then add the result; repeat till it reaches the total number of words in a file. The problem is with the assignment of `cur` variable, which should store the output of pipe operation (`grep  | wc -w`). Once this statement is reached `cur:command not found` appears on a terminal. I am using Cygwin. How can I make it work?

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

a=($(wc test.txt))
filename=$dir/freq.txt
touch $filename

words=${a[1]} #words variable stores the total number of words in test.txt file
total=0 
count=1 #first check the number of words of length 1

while [ "$total" -ne "$words" ] #terminate once total equals words
do
    cur = $(grep -o -w "\w\{$count\}" male-first.txt | wc -w) #number of words of length count
    echo "$count: $cur"
    let count++ #increment count
    let total=total+cur #add number of words of length count to total
done

echo "Done"
```

Comment: For what it's worth this isn't cygwin-specific either.  In bash on any system variable assignments don't take spaces around the `=`.  Without a space it just looks like you're trying to run a program named `cur` which takes as its first argument `=`, and there's no way the shell can distinguish from that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't allow space around assignments:

```
cur=$(grep...
```